# Code does not continue after the return ok() from web api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, blazor-webassembly

**Hello im building a simple program just to learn asp webapi and blazor, my post function  is working fine it was tested on postman here is my code for your observation : **

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("addSingleProduct")]
        public IActionResult Post([FromBody] ProductModel product)
        {
            try
            {
                if (product == null)
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }
                if (product != null)
                {
                    _conn.Open();
                    string query = "INSERT INTO Product VALUES (@ProdName, @ProdPrice,@ProdDesc,@ProdImg,@CatgId,@ProdFam)";
                    using (Def.cmd = new SqlCommand(query,_conn))
                    {
                        Def.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProdName", product.ProdName);
                        Def.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProdPrice", product.ProdPrice);
                        Def.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProdDesc", product.ProdDesc);
                        Def.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProdImg", product.ProdImg);
                        Def.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CatgId", product.CatgId);
                        Def.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProdFam", product.ProdFam);

                        //Def.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        int rowsAffected = Def.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        if (rowsAffected == 0)
                        {
                            _conn.Close();
                            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "Failed to insert product");
                        }
                    }
                    _conn.Close();                   
                }
                return Ok();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                _conn.Close();
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "Failed to insert product");
            }
        }
```

**in my Blazor app im awaiting the response to place the value in a boolean so i can show the user that the product was added **

```
@if(isadded==true){
    <h1>Product was added</h1>
}else{
    <h1>Product was not added</h1>
}

@code {
    private bool isadded;
    [Inject]
    private GetProductsService productService { get; set; }

    private ProductModel product = new ProductModel();

    protected async Task<bool> AddNewProduct()
    {
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await productService.AddProduct(product);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                isadded = true;
            }
            else
            {
                string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine($"AddProduct failed with status code {response.StatusCode}: {responseContent}");
                isadded  = false;
            }
            return isadded;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**And here is my service where i make the api call**

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> AddProduct(ProductModel product)
        {
            return await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Product/AddSingleProduct", product);          
        }
```

**The code runs smoothly the model is being sent to the api and inserted in the database but when it hits return ok() nothing happens and the debugging stops so im not able to tell the user that the product was added **

Comment: Show us how you call AddNewProduct()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue is with the `isadded` boolean value not being updated properly in your Blazor component.

In your code, you're calling the `AddNewProduct()` method asynchronously, but you're not awaiting the result when calling it. This means that the `isadded` value might not be updated by the time the code is executed, causing it to always show "Product was not added".

To fix this, you should await the AddNewProduct() method when calling it:

```
protected async Task AddNewProduct()
{
    isadded = await productService.AddProduct(product);

    StateHasChanged();
}
```

In your `GetProductsService` class, you should modify the `AddProduct()` method to return a bool value instead of an HttpResponseMessage:

```
public async Task<bool> AddProduct(ProductModel product)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Product/AddSingleProduct", product);          
    return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
}
```

By doing this, you're returning a boolean value indicating whether the product was added or not.

Then, in your Blazor component, you can update the `AddNewProduct()` method to use the returned boolean value:

```
protected async Task AddNewProduct()
{
    isadded = await productService.AddProduct(product);

    StateHasChanged();
}
```

With these changes, the `isadded` value should be properly updated and the UI should display the correct message based on whether the product was added or not.

Comment: The StateHasChanged() should not be necessary. You are correct that AddNewProduct() should be awaited, we need to see that code.

Comment: Fair enough, thank you for the clarity on my answer!